# SSIS package help to migrate data from MySQL server to SQL Server 2008 daily?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, bids

I am trying to write up an SSIS package which would migrate queried data from MySQL server to SQL Server. I would need to modify a particular column say "stream" (DT_I4) values (1 would be 2 , 2 would become 4, etc just some random 4 integer replacements) and then check another column value(emp_id) if it exists in SQL Server before inserting. if it exists, do not insert and if it does not, then we write these values.

I am a SSIS newbie, so far I have been able to add both ADO.NET source and ADO.NET destination. I need help with the following

1. Should I use a derived column or script component to convert the values
2. How do i check if emp-id exists in SQL Server
3. How do I map the errors?
4. What is the best practice to implement the above situation, thanks for reading and for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it is better to use the stock components to accomplish a task than to write a custom script. Performance and maintenance are two big reasons for that advice. Also, don't try to do too many things in a single transformation. The pipeline can really take advantage of parallelization if you let it.

1) Specifically speaking, perhaps I didn't understand where the conversion needs to happen in your problem description but I would start with neither a [Derived Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx) nor a [Script Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137640.aspx). Instead, for a straight type conversion I'd use [Data Conversion Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141706.aspx).

Rereading it, perhaps you are attempting a *value* conversion. Depending on the complexity, it could be accomplished with a derived column or two and worst case, drop to a script task but, even better-does the data **need** to come over with the unmapped value? Toss a CASE statement in your source query and skip the SSIS complexity with mapping value A to value B.

2) The [Lookup Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx) will help you in this department. It is important to note that failure to find a value would result in the package failing in 2005. 2008+ the option for handling not-found rows is more readily available. There is an output path "Redirect Rows to No Match Output" and this is the path you will want to use as you only want the rows that don't already exist. As a general guideline on a Lookup, only pull back the columns of interest as the package will cache that lookup locally. That does not go well on server memory when it's a hundreds of millions of rows and 80+ columns wide.

3) What errors? Conversion errors? Lookup errors? Some-other-error-not-defined? In general, you'll probably want to read about [Integration Services Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139791.aspx). Everything in a data flow has an Error path leading out of it. Most everything has 1+ non-error paths leading out. In cases where there are multiple non-error paths available, when you connect them to the next component, BIDS will ask which output you are intending to use.

4) Knowing the extremely general problem defined, your package may look something like
[image: generic dataflow]

Refine your question if that doesn't address the specifics.